# How to mock a method call in JUnit when the method is inside a base class and the testing method class extends it?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need to write unit test in JUnit for a method, the method is inside class A and class A extends Class B. My testing method methodA() calls another methodB() which is inside class B. So how should I mock this methodB() call so that when I call methodA() from my testCase, and when It calls methodB() it gets the mocked value and gets the test case passed?
Which class should I mock, classA or Class B?

```
    ///logDaoImpl class extends BaseDaoImpl
    @Override
    public List<Log> LogAll(long fromIndex,long toIndex) {
    String query = "from Log ";
    QueryCondition qd = new QueryCondition();   
    qd.setIgnoreCount(false);
    qd.addAndCondition("id", ">=" , "long", fromIndex);
    List<Log> result = findByCustomNamedQuery(query, qd);   //findByCustomNamedQuery method is from my extended class 

   return result;
}

    public class BaseDaoImpl extends JpaDaoSupport implements BaseDao {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;


public List findByCustomNamedQuery(String query, QueryCondition qd) {

    if (qd.hasConditions()) {
        query += qd.getCondition() + qd.getOrderBy();
    }

    EntityManager em = getJpaTemplate().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createQuery(query);    
    String[] namedParams = StringUtils.substringsBetween(query, ":", " ");
    if (namedParams != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < namedParams.length; i++) {
            q.setParameter(namedParams[i], qd.getParamValue(namedParams[i]));
        }
    }

    if (!qd.isIgnoreCount()) {
        q.setFirstResult(qd.start());
        q.setMaxResults(qd.count());
    }

    List result =  q.getResultList();
    em.close();
    return result;
}


//test class 
  public void testLogAll() {

  List<Log>expL=new ArrayList<Log>();
    expL.add(Log);//added sample test log object from setup method
    String query = "from Log ";
    QueryCondition qd=new QueryCondition();
    qd.setIgnoreCount(false);
    qd.addAndCondition("id", ">=" , "long", 0L);
    LogDaoImpl obj=Mockito.spy(LogDaoImpl.class);
    when(obj.findByCustomNamedQuery(query,qd)).thenReturn(expL);
    List<UnbanLog> expResult = expL;
    List<UnbanLog> result = obj.LogAll(0L, 20L);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

Comment: I know this is pretty much basic thing but I didn't find any answer. Let me know if you know the answer.

Comment: I have added the class and method, can you please have a look on it now

Comment: When the solution suggested doesnt work, then provide a [mcve] within your question that shows us how you try to use it!

Comment: You inject entityManager and use a self-created em. If you would use entityManager, you could mock and inject it in your JUnit-Test.

Answer (score 0):

When ClassA extends ClassB, you have to spy ClassA, so some mehtods will be mocked, for the rest is called the original:

```
@Test
public void methodATest() {
    ClassA obj = Mockito.spy(ClassA.class);
    Mockito.when(obj.methodB()).thenReturn(6);
    Assert.assertEquals(10, obj.methodA());

}
```

Comment: I think that is the correct answer. No idea why it was downvoted, especially without any comment.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample code, please check again now. I tried with spy but it returns null exception

Comment: where's the NPE?

Comment: `when(obj.findByCustomNamedQuery(query,qd)).thenReturn(expL);` Try to mockk with any, don't know wether QueryCondition has overriden hash and equals...

Comment: I tried this before posting the question here. Unfortunately, this did not work for me.

Comment: 1. You didn't answer my question, 2. did you try it with spy before posting the question?

Comment: Yes, I tried spy and stub but failed. Could you give me any idea on this?